# TP-Link Router isolates clients

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have TP-Link TL-WR841N router with approx 8 devices connected regularly. Recently I've been noticing that the router isolates connected devices from each other despite the checkbox of "Client Isolation" being unchecked.
Just to verify, I enabled and disabled Client Isolation and the problem seemed cured. But, after an hour, devices again couldn't ping each other. What could be causing the issue?

Some points which I think might be helpful:

1) I'd hard reset the router less than a week ago. The only modification I've done since then is setting up a few DHCP reservations.

2) My ISP provides internet through Static IP mode.

Comment: Do a hard reset of the router back to factory specifications, set up and make sure Client Isolation is OFF.

Comment: @John I've added some points to my question. Please go through them

Comment: I am not sure about your router. In my router (Cisco Small Office) , isolation is a "per device" setting and the default for all devices is OFF.

Comment: @John I carefully checked again. No individual options in mine